# Trying to send mail and app crashed

Tags: ios

I'm trying to use FMailComposeViewController to send a email message. When I try to send the mail by calling presentModalViewController the app crashes.  In the emulateR it crashes all time time on the device it crashes like half the time.

I do not get a error message, but app freezes and debuuger shows it going to
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
also apps always crashes in simulater, about half the time on iPhone.

code:

```
- (IBAction)aEmail:(id)sender {
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailCtrl = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailCtrl setSubject:@"Your TellaFortune Card Reading"];
    [mailCtrl setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tedpottel@yahoo.com"]];
    mailCtrl.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailCtrl setMessageBody:  @"hello"  isHTML: false];

 // CRASHES ON THID LINE
    [self presentModalViewController:mailCtrl animated:NO];
    //      [mailCtrl release];

}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[ UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Cannot send email"
                        message: @"Please check internet connection and email set up"
                        delegate: self
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                        otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];
}

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// if you do not have thid methed when sending emsil, app will freez after
// sent or cancel button has been pressed.

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"Email result: %@", result==MFMailComposeResultCancelled?@"Cancelled":
      result==MFMailComposeResultSaved?@"Saved":
      result==MFMailComposeResultSent?@"Sent":
      result==MFMailComposeResultFailed?@"Failed":@"Unknown");
}
```

Comment: Please update post with the error message you see in the console.

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator? I've seen it be wonky on the simulator. Test it on a real device. Also try just using `[self presentViewController]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the mailctrl in an ivar - you have no strong reference to it now.

Comment: It is unnecessary to keep strong reference to the controller which being presented.

Comment: hi, could you explain what you mean by putting it in a lvar, thank you

Comment: You are creating the object using a local variable in the method. Don't you know what an objective c ivar is - an instance variable. You would make 'MFMailComposeViewController *mailCtrl' an instance variable, set it where you do now, and in the delegate methods nil it out (set it to nil) when its finished doing its work.